# Java Restaurant Menu, calculation issue

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the total for a menu item, I cannot quite figure out how to get the code to take the proper inputs and read them as item values. I need it to register that the user wants say 2 pizzas that are 12$ each for a total of 24, however I cannot figure it out. Here is what I have.

```
package javaapplication4;

/**
 *
 * @author Travis
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication4 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    float Chicken = 9;
    float Pizza = 12;
    float Veal = 15;
    float Alfredo = 9;
    float Garlic = 8;
    float Veggie = 7;
    float Spaghetti = 9;
    float Raviolli = 7;
    float Meat = 8;
    float Canolli = 5;
       // Display menu and prices 


    System.out.println("1. Chicken $9");

    System.out.println("2. Pizza $12");

    System.out.println("3. Veal $15");

    System.out.println("4. Alfredo $9");

    System.out.println("5. Garlic $8");

    System.out.println("6. Veggie  $7");

    System.out.println("7. Spaghetti $9");

    System.out.println("8. Raviolli $7");

    System.out.println("9. Meat $8");

    System.out.println("10. Canolli 5$");

System.out.print("Enter your menu choice name: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);           

        int orderNumber = input.nextInt();

   //prompt user for quantity

        System.out.print("How many would you like?: ");

        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int orderAmount = input.nextInt();

//Switch to determine price

    double price = orderNumber + orderAmount;

    switch (orderNumber) {

        case 1:  price = Chicken ;
                 break;
        case 2:  price = Pizza;
                 break;
        case 3:  price = Veal;
                 break;
        case 4:  price = Alfredo;
                 break;
        case 5:  price = Garlic;
                 break;
        case 6:  price = Veggie;
                 break;
        case 7:  price = Spaghetti;
                 break;
        case 8:  price = Raviolli;
                 break;
        case 9:  price = Meat;
                 break;
        case 10: price = Canolli;
                 break;

    }
    System.out.println("Your total is " + price);


    System.out.println("Please enter your payment amount");
    int payment = input.nextInt();
    double total = payment - price;
    System.out.println ("Thank you your change is $" + total);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your switch statement (you're never really using it).

You should have something like this:

```
double price = 0.0;  //You will reassign this

switch (orderNumber) {

    case 1:  price = Chicken ;
             break;
    case 2:  price = Pizza;
             break;
    case 3:  price = Veal;
             break;
    case 4:  price = Alfredo;
             break;
    case 5:  price = Garlic;
             break;
    case 6:  price = Veggie;
             break;
    case 7:  price = Spaghetti;
             break;
    case 8:  price = Raviolli;
             break;
    case 9:  price = Meat;
             break;
    case 10: price = Canolli;
             break;

double total_price = price * orderAmount; //You currently have this as an addition
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have been working on this literally all day. Dumb mistakes on my part!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
double price = orderNumber + orderAmount;
```

I think it should be:

```
double price = orderNumber * orderAmount;
```